# How can i export a model on gltf format with texture?

Tags: modeling, texturing, materials, export, file-format

I made a 3D model on Blender, where it shows the texture working without problem (psd file, i also tried with png format of the same image)
[image]

But when i try to export it, the model can be seen on Windows (11) but the texture is nowhere to be seen.
[image]

Does anyone know how to fix this problem? The model is low poly, the texture/material is the same as in the picture, but when opening it on the viewer it doesnt show textures at all.

Answer (score 2):

The exporters that come with Blender mostly only recognize very simple graphs using the default Principled node. In your case you should use

[image: Image Texture node connected to Principled's Base Color and Alpha inputs]

If you're using alpha, you also need to set the Blend Mode in the Properties editor (if using Cycles, look under "Viewport Display"). Use Alpha Blend for partial translucency, or Alpha Clip for cut-out style transparency. (Also consider turning on Backface Culling.)

[image: Blend Mode set to Alpha Blend]

The default Principled node doesn't quite match your Diffuse node setup though. To make it match exactly, you'd need to set the Principled's Specular to 0.0 instead of 0.5. However **Specular doesn't get exported to glTF** (glTF material always use 0.5 basically). So recommend the next best thing: **set the Roughness to 1.0**.

You can read most of this and more in the [manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/import_export/scene_gltf2.html#blend-modes).

Comment: Nope, sadly, it still doesnt do anything, just made a new scene with a basic cube and a texture like the first one you told me to do without even transparency and it doesnt export it at all with texture. Is there any other format that is not glTF that can be easily be exported with Blender and easily be open with any viewer?

Comment: It looks like your texture is in `.psd` format? May need to convert to PNG or JPG to export. The example above should certainly work with the glTF exporter in Blender 2.80+. I'm not sure what other formats support PBR materials in Blender...

Comment: Exporter should convert to .png/.jpg for you. It works with a .psd for me.